# How to "set" and "puts" variable, which name consists of string and another variable?

Tags: variables, set, tcl, puts

I' trying to get a value of variable, which name consists of string "a" and iterator "i" (in this short example I skipped for loop). I was trying to do it with concat and append, with [] and "" and nothing working. Is there any solution for this problem?

```
set b0 0
set i 0
set a$i $b$i (here is my problem)
puts $a$i
```

puts should show "0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from a variable whose name is computed, use `set` with only one argument:

```
set a$i [set b$i]
puts [set a$i]
```

(There's a real sense in which the `$` is a syntactic shorthand for calling this form of `set`; indeed, the `$` syntax is newer.)

## But Use Arrays Instead

In this case, you are almost certainly better off rewriting your code to use associative arrays.

```
set b(0) 0
set i 0
set a($i) $b($i)
puts $a($i)
```

Comment: For completeness, aliasing variables with `upvar 0` is also a possible to get easy-to-manipulate names. It makes sense in some situations, but probably not this one.